# Pine Script double position size if the last trade was in loss (Martingale)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My code did not make its function to enter with double position size if the last trade was in loss. can you figure my mistake?

```
//Open Trades
//
//
// Calculate the current position size
var float positionSize = strategy.position_size != 0 ? strategy.position_size : na
if (not na(positionSize))
    positionSize := positionSize >= 0 ? positionSize : -positionSize

// Determine if the last trade was a loss
var bool lastTradeLoss = strategy.losstrades[0] > strategy.losstrades[1]

// Determine the position size multiplier
var float multiplier = lastTradeLoss ? 2.0 : 1.0

// Calculate the new position size
var float newPositionSize = multiplier * positionSize

if (buy and strategy.position_size <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=newPositionSize)
else if (buy and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=positionSize)

if (sell and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty=newPositionSize)
else if (sell and strategy.position_size <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty=positionSize)

strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Long", profit=600, loss = 2000)
strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Short", profit=600, loss = 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using a var declaration in the wrong place. You probably don't fully understand how it works. The var declaration allows you to initialize a variable only once, and keep this value in the series unchanged on bars until the next deliberate reassignment, for which there is a separate operator.
2. You are trying to identify a losing trade by comparing the number of losing trades on the current and previous bar. Your condition will only be true on the exit bar of a losing trade. There is no guarantee that this condition will be true the next time you enter a trade after a losing one.
   Try to check if the profit of the previous closed trade was negative, it will work better `strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades-1) < 0`

Comment: Could you please correct it for. me as I tried to fix it but I failed :(
Thanks in advanced

Comment: @Karim -- If you've tried to fix it, than please update your post to include your attempt, and tell us *where* you failed. Don't expect people to do your work, especially when the given advice is as clear as that by vgladkov.